# Associative array not an array when passed to controller thru AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to pass this array `var data_array` into my controller thru AJAX

This is the value of `var data_array` when I use `alert(JSON.stringify(data_array));`

[image]

This is my AJAX method

```
var project_details = $.extend({}, data_array);

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url('PPMP_controller/submitPPMP'); ?>",
       data: { data_array : $.param(project_details) },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert('PPMP submission success!');
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function(errorw) {
           console.log(errorw);
       }
   });
```

This is my PPMP_controller

```
public function submitPPMP(){
    $data_array = $this->input->post('data_array');
    $value = $this->PPMP_model->submitPPMP($data_array);
    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

This is my model

```
function submitPPMP($data_array){
    $date_format = 'DATE_W3C';

    $date_submitted = standard_date($date_format);
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => 1,
        'date_submitted' => $date_submitted,
        'first_lvl_status' => 0,
        'second_lvl_status' => 0,
        'third_lvl_status' => 0,
        'fourth_lvl_status' => 0,
        'submitted' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('project', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    if(is_array($data_array) || is_object($data_array)){
        return "yes";
        foreach($data_array as $object){
            $project_details = array(
                'project_id' => $id,
                'supply_id' => $object->supply_id,
                'supply_description' => $object->supply_description,
                'quantity' => $object->quantity,
                'price' => $object->price,
                'jan' => $object->jan,
                'feb' => $object->feb,
                'mar' => $object->mar,
                'apr' => $object->apr,
                'may' => $object->may,
                'jun' => $object->jun,
                'jul' => $object->jul,
                'aug' => $object->aug,
                'sep' => $object->sep,
                'oct' => $object->oct,
                'nov' => $object->nov,
                'dec' => $object->dec
            );
            $this->db->insert('project_details', $project_details);
        }
    }
    else{
        return "no";
    }
    return $this->db->last_query();
}
```

However the array passed from controller to model is not an array since it doesn't go thru the line `if(is_array($data_array) || is_object($data_array))` instead it goes to the `else` condition and `return "no"`.

What might be causing this array not being passed an array from controller to model. Thank you for the help. I am using Codeigniter 3.0 as an MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing json to your model not array , when it comes to your model it should be ,

try `var_dump($data_array)` to check its data type i.e `json` or `object` or `array`

```
$data_array = json_decode($data_array); // to get object    
$data_array = json_decode($data_array,true); // to get array
```

Your `PPMP_controller` should be

```
public function submitPPMP(){
    $data_array = $this->input->post('data_array');
    $data_array = json_decode($data_array); 
    $value = $this->PPMP_model->submitPPMP($data_array);
    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting `$data_array = json_decode($data_array);` to both model and controller but my model still `return "no"`

Comment: try `var_dump($data_array)` to check what data type is being pass to your model or controller ?

Comment: Where should i put `var_dump($data_array);` coz when i put it after doing `$data_array = json_decode($data_array);` nothing happens. Maybe because of the AJAX request?

Comment: add a die after dump and check your ajax response in network

Comment: I added a `die();` after the `var_dump($data_array);` in my model but nothing happens and there is no AJAX response but there is an object in my console that when I click leads me to the `error: function(errorw)` of my codes.

Comment: I tried `echo json_encode(gettype($data_array));` and it returns `NULL`